# Как реализовать выделение памяти для пользователей сайта на php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, dropbox

Нужно для каждого пользователя выделять память на сервере, чи возможно викорисовуваты АPI для этого, что-то типа Dropbox или AWS S3? Чтобы пользователь не мог загрузить на сервер файлов более чем n GB

Answer (score 0):

Создайте табличку в БД, где ведите учет общего размера загруженного контента пользователем. При достижении лимита, соответственно отказывать в загрузке